# How to plot histogram of x and y values?

Tags: r, histogram

Today I want to learn a little bit about the R statistical programming language.

I'm not finding the tutorials to be helpful yet.

I hope to jumpstart this effort with a simple task.

I have 3 x values: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5
and    3 y values: 1.2, 0.1, 4.4

I want to plot a histogram with this data.

q1: What is the least amount of R syntax I can use to plot this historgram?

q2: Can I put the data in myfile.csv and ask R to read myfile.csv and then plot the histogram?

Comment: "I'm not finding the tutorials to be helpful yet . . ."  That's not sounding good.  You might want to try another language.

Comment: For q2: `?read.csv`.  Make sure you include a header row, because `read.csv` expects one by default.

Comment: I typed ?read.csv at r-prompt and got good info.  The tip about header row was golden. This simple thread on stackoverflow dot com has made my interactions with R tutorials MUCH easier!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5), y=c(1.2, 0.1, 4.4))
barplot(dat$y, names.arg=dat$x, ylim=c(0,5))
```

That will do what you're after. I think. Labels can be added like so.

```
barplot(dat$y, names.arg=dat$x, ylim=c(0,5), ylab="blah", xlab="lol")
```

[image]

A histogram has bars touching (continuous x variable), and bar chart/plot doesn't, strictly speaking, so this may not be what you're after...

Comment: of course you could use `space=0` if you did want them touching.

Answer (score 1):

Er, do you mean a scatter-plot, or a three-dimensional histogram with `(x,y)` pairs of `(1.5,1.2)`, `(2.5,0.1)`, and `(3.5,4.4)`?  If the former, just use [`plot(x,y)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/plot.html) to get the scatterplot, use [`write`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/write.html) to output the data to file, and use [`read.csv`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to read the data from a csv file.

Comment: No, I dont want a scatter-plot.  I want a 2D histogram.  I want it to have 3 bars.  The first bar has height of 1.2.  It's location on the x axis is 1.5. And so on.

Comment: @Huck Smith ...err then that is *not* a histogram. A histogram is a crude estimate of the probability density function of a univariate (in the conventional sense of a histogram) variable. Hence, in a histogram the x-axis represents the single variable and the y-axis is the estimate of the density of the data at values on the scale of `x`. By the sounds of it, you want a `barplot()`

Comment: The information about plot(), write(), and read.csv() were very useful to me.  The terminology related to plot and histogram is something I can use.  I need to understand the distinctions between terms like distribution, histogram, and plot. I'm gaining some of that here; thanks.